# Adding the onclick event to a field of each row in the Ajax datatables in HTML

Tags: javascript, json, datatable

I have a datatables table that uses JSON data to display information in the table.
I put the desired link along with its ID on one of the fields of each row so that the user can enter the page specific to the details of each field .
But now, instead of using the a tag, I want to create an onclick event that will open a web page for me by calling window.open('https://somewhere').
I want to set an event on the data that comes from the title
I did a short search on the internet but did not find any results
Thank you for your help

The general form of codes related to the table and table script

table structure :

```
<table class="datatables-basic table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>schoolName</th>
                    <th>HeadName</th>
                    <th>PhoneNumber</th>
                    <th>HeadPhoneNumber</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>IsActive</th>
                    <th>DO</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
 </table>
```

table script (DataTable):

```
 $(function () {

            var dt_basic_table = $('.datatables-basic'),
                dt_basic;

            // DataTable with buttons
            // --------------------------------------------------------------------

            if (dt_basic_table.length) {
                var listFilesUrl = "https://localhost:44309/AllSchools";
                dt_basic = dt_basic_table.DataTable({
                    ajax: listFilesUrl,
                    columns: [
                        { data: '' },
                        { data: 'schoolId' },
                        { data: 'schoolId' },

                        //I want to set an event on the data that comes from the title
                        { data: 'title',
                            render: function (data, type, row) {
                                return $('<a>')
                                    .attr({ target: "_blank", href:"https://localhost:44309/RenderSchool?schoolId=" + row.schoolId })
                                    .text(data)
                                    .wrap('<div></div>')
                                    .parent()
                                    .html();
                            }
                        },

                        { data: null,
                            render: function (data, type, row){
                                var details = row.headFirstName + " " + row.headLastName;
                                return details;
                            }
                        },
                        { data: 'phoneNumber' },
                        { data: 'headPhoneNumber' },
                        { data: 'address' },
                        { data: 'isActive' },
                        { data: '' }
                    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question (which is not really a question):

> I want to set an event on the data that comes from the title.

You can add a class to the relevant column - DataTables has an [option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className) for that, e.g.: `className: "clickable"`.

Then you can use that class name as the target for a jQuery [delegated event](http://api.jquery.com/on/) handler.

In this demo, you can click on any cell in the **Title** column. Here, I just print the text to the console. You can use it to build your URL.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
      dataSrc: ""
    },
    columns: [{
        title: "User ID",
        data: "userId"
      },
      {
        title: "ID",
        data: "id"
      },
      {
        title: "Title",
        data: "title",
        className: "clickable" //,
        //render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
        //   whatever you want in here
        //} 
      }
    ]

  });

  $("table").on("click", "td.clickable", function() {
    let cellText = $(this).text();
    // window.open( 'https://' + cellText );
    console.log(cellText);
  });

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%"></table>

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Note how the event is actually attached to the `<table>`, as in `$( "table" ).on(...)` to ensure that the event still fires, even when you navigate to another page in the DataTable.